# How to fire event when user clicks outside Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

When you are editing a text field, and you click outside that text field, a "blur" event fires on that text field element that you can do fun stuff with.

I'm building a Google map where you're editing a line, and I want to do some fun stuff when a user clicks outside the map. (i.e. deselect the current path, and start a new path when the map is clicked again)

Catching a click event on the page in general feels clumsy.  Is there a google maps equivalent of the "blur" or "focusout" event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a dom listener to the map overlay for the blur event.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#DomEvents

Comment: It's a bummer, but I think you're right.  This is about the best I can do.

Honestly, I shouldn't be expecting a google maps instance to behave like a text field.